# Using php7.0-fpm instead php5-fpm for nginx

Tags: php, nginx

After updating from php5.6 to php7, i updated php5-fpm to php7.0-fpm. And then i changed my config file for nginx, that's it:

```
server {
    root /home/user/project/public_html/frontend/web;
    index index.php;
    server_name project-local;

    access_log /home/user/log/project.access.log ;
    error_log /home/user/log/project.error.log notice;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location @phpfpm {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And i noticed in the log file, that the php5-fpm.socket is used, not php7.0-fpm.socket. That's a error log file:

```
[error] 2001#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: project-local, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "project-local"
```

i tried to turn php5-fpm off, but anyway it is used.

Somobody faced with kind of problem?

Comment: Either `nginx` is reading a different file - or the process has not been restarted. Use `nginx -T` to find out why.

Comment: i am so sorry i did so stupid mistake. I had 2 config files which linked to 1 hostname, but these files had different names and i didn't check them. I checked it only after your tip. Ty so much